# Regression on estimated variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, standard-error, measurement-error

I'm making a two-step analysis for my data.

First Step: I've collected inflation and interest rate data for 25 countries in a monthly frequency for the last 20 years. I run a simple linear of inflation (right side, X) on interest rate (left side, y) for each country.
At the end of this step, I have 25 coefficients for inflation - one for each country - and, of course, the standard errors of these measures.

Second Step: I want to run a regression of the coefficients taken of the first step on specific data sets I have for the countries (all including 25 observations, 1 for each country). As far as I know, this second step should be taken with precaution, because I'll be using estimated variables as dependent variables (Y).

What is the specific treatment and care that I should have on the second step?